# Git says "this does not look like a git repository.. exiting" but my commit works anyways

Tags: git

I make a commit:

```
$ git commit -m 'Add comment'
```

And I get this message:

```
env: git: No such file or directory
this does not look like a git repository.. exiting
[my-branch af881ac] Add comment
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

I thought the commit failed, because git doesn't even think there's a repository, but it didn't fail. It worked — I see it when I run `git log`.

What's going on here?

Comment: Do you have `git` aliased to a shell script that does something else too by chance?

Comment: What happened when you tried to do `git add` beforehand?

Comment: Output of `git --version` and `which git` please. Also, what OS?

Comment: As poke commented, what is the output of `type git` and `which git`?